# How does the element $ ba^{n} $ become $a^{3n}b $ from the relation $ ab=ba^{3}$ of the group $ D_{4}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups

moving $a^{n}$ past b it makes sense for me for this to become $a^{n/3}b $ rather than $a^{3n}b$ from the given relation. Am I missing something obvious here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$bab=a^3\implies (bab)^n=ba^nb=a^{3n}\implies ba^n=a^{3n}b$$

Remember *all the time* that $\;b^{-1}=b\;$ ...

Comment: Many thanks! Just one more question, I know that $b^2=e $ but how does this imply that $b^{n}=b$?

Comment: @chloeloughan It doesn't. In fact, $$b^n=\begin{cases}1,&n\;\text{ is even}\\b,& n\;\text{ n is odd}\end{cases}$$

Comment: In that case for $ D_{4} $ shouldn't we have $b^{n}=1$ as 4 is even?

Comment: @chloeloughan Yes, of course....and $\;b^4=b^6=b^{1000}=1\;$ ...so what?

Comment: My point is that in your answer above you used that $b^{n}=b$ but we are in talking about the group $D_{4}$ in which n is even so it should be 1?

Comment: @chloeloughan No, I didn't use anything of the like. Perhaps you meant that $$(bab)^n=(bab)(bab)\cdot\ldots\cdot(bab)=(ba)\,\overbrace{bb}^{=e}\,a(bb)a\cdot\ldots\cdot (bb)(ab)=ba^nb$$

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much.